# Solve Algebraic Riccati Equation in R

Tags: r, kalman-filter

I know that it's quite simple to solve the equation in Matlab. But is there a way to solve it in R as well? I need it for my Kalman filter implementations.

Comment: In Matlab, it's the "dare" function: 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dare.html

Comment: Short of coding it up yourself, it doesn't look like there are any packaged implementations. Scipy has http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_are.html which might give you some useful source code: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.1/scipy/linalg/_solvers.py#L300-L374

Comment: I have recently updated the scipy solvers which will be available in v0.19 you can see the docs and the extended code in the development version of scipy docs http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_continuous_are.html#scipy.linalg.solve_continuous_are